# How to create File uploading in php mysql?

Tags: file, uploading, download

I was trying to create winrar uploading files in php + mysql. I am successfully create image uploading area but this is really hard to me to create winrar uploading and downloading. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from freedompeace:

```
.rar    application/x-rar-compressed, application/octet-stream
.zip    application/zip, application/octet-stream
```

I would do a check on the file name too. Here is how you could check if the file is a RAR or ZIP file. I tested it by creating a quick command line application.

```
<?php

if (isRarOrZip($argv[1])) {
   echo 'It is probably a RAR or ZIP file.';
} else {
   echo 'It is probably not a RAR or ZIP file.';
}

function isRarOrZip($file) {
// get the first 7 bytes
$bytes = file_get_contents($file, FALSE, NULL, 0, 7);
$ext = strtolower(substr($file, - 4));

// RAR magic number: Rar!\x1A\x07\x00
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR
if ($ext == '.rar' and bin2hex($bytes) == '526172211a0700') {
    return TRUE;
}

// ZIP magic number: none, though PK\003\004, PK\005\006 (empty archive), 
// or PK\007\008 (spanned archive) are common.
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)
if ($ext == '.zip' and substr($bytes, 0, 2) == 'PK') {
    return TRUE;
}

 return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Notice that it still won't be 100% certain, but it is probably good enough.

```
$ rar.exe l somefile.zip
somefile.zip is not RAR archive
```

But even WinRAR detects non RAR files as SFX archives:

```
$ rar.exe l somefile.srr
SFX Volume somefile.srr
```